# Working with abandoned pull requests on Github (keeping history)

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have a repo on Github, and user opened a pull request there. But now his PR is outdated (rebase needed or I want to ask an author to fix a couple of issues). How can I do that if the user doesn't want to make fixes or lost interest to the project?

I can create a patch and apply locally, but then I will lose a user's commits, so, I'll hijack his/her contribution.

How can I pull abandoned PR to own repo, make own fixes and create another PR, keeping a history of user's contribution?

Comment: How about forking that user's repo (the branch for the PR), working in that fork, and finally creating a new PR from that fork?

Comment: Yes, that's possible - but sometimes user's branch is already deleted. I want more generic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the user's repository as a remote in your local repository and fetch from this repository. You should get the remote branch containing all the commits of the PR.

Then, you could do what you want, fix by adding new commits, rebase or merge... That's up to you.

And then after, you should do a new PR.

Comment: But what if user's branch is already deleted? Pull request stays available in this case btw

Comment: If user branch is deleted, that's a little harder. You will have to modify the remote of the upstream repository to fetch also the pull request branches. I don't remember exactly the syntax (but should be foundable) but should be something like 'pr/1' (where 1 will be replaced by each PR id)